# How to open an Url using In-App Browser from a flutter application from a button click?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, inappbrowser

I am developing a flutter project and i want to open a Url using an in-app browser when a button in clicked. I don't want the browser to leave the flutter application. What are the possible ways to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can try https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a Webview.

Look at https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter